# Google compute engine Debian, $PATH getting reset after exiting from Putty

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine, path

I have a debian instance on Google cloud. I needed to host a Play! Framework project. For this I installed a software Activator and added it to path as follows

```
export PATH=/home/user/activator-dist-1.3.12/bin:$PATH
```

All is well, activator gets added. I wire in my project fro GIT and start the Play! server.

I test APIs with POST MAN and its working. So I exit from Putty.

Next time, I login to Putty again and eagerly type the `"activator"` command in shell, and it tells me `"Command not found"`.

I check the $PATH with echo and see that it has been reset to its initial value and does not contain activator/bin path.

Could someone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the var with the export command will only change it for that session. You can set your PATH environment var in the /etc/environment file. It will then be permanently set for all users.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. When I modified environment file, I was connected through Putty. I added the line `export PATH=/home/user/activator-dist-1.3.12/bin:$PATH` to the end of environment file. But when i type activator command it says "Command not found". But typing `export PATH=/home/user/activator-dist-1.3.12/bin:$PATH` in shell works. Why could this be happening?

Comment: You should remove 'export' from the /etc/environment file. So it should say "PATH=/home/user/activator-dist-1.3.12/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Removed the word `export`. Still the same. Its not being added to PATH. Is it different for Debian?